# I need help setting the value of HTML value input type check box based on whether or not an ASP:Checkbox is checked

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, checkbox

My situation is as follows;

I am converting a few Infopath forms into aspx web forms. In my aspx form, there are about 50 checkboxes. When the end-user submits the form, it needs to generate an html formatted email to a user group. I have no issues with the email generation, of all things I've hit a block where I cannot figure out how to set the value of the HTML checkboxes based upon the asp checkboxes. I'll give an example of what I'm trying to do below.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="RestraintCB" runat="server" Text="Restraint Event" />
```

If the above check box is checked, on form submission, I need the HTML check box to be marked check.
Now if you know how to set up email with C# from code behind then you will understand my frustration.

```
InsMail.Body = @"<input id='RestraintCB' type='checkbox' />Restraint Event"
```

If I have lost you yet, I just need to get the true/false value from the asp:CheckBox to the HTML input type checkbox. Keep in mind that the ENTIRE email is generated from a VERY LONG string and I cannot directly interact with ANY of the HTML elements.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution, and if you can think of a more simple one that would be greatly appreciated.
Okay so here we go. Remember there are about 50 asp:CheckBoxs in my form. Okay, so every checkbox now has an OnClick event. The OnClick event is called Checkboxes_CheckChanged and it is setup as followed:

```
protected void Checkboxes_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
    var chkBoxID = chkBox.ID;
    Label chkBoxLabel = (Label)FindControl(chkBoxID + "Label");
    if(chkBox.Checked == true)
    {
        chkBoxLabel.Text = "checked";
    }
    if(chkBox.Checked == false)
    {
        chkBoxLabel.Text = "";
    }
}
```

So basically, when I change the checked value of a checkbox, it changes the Text of it's corresponding label which is of course hidden.
So if I have;

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="CheckBox1" />
```

It has a corresponding label;

```
<asp:Label ID="CheckBox1Label" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false" />
```

NOW, when I generate the email, it's one GIANT block of what is essentially InnerHtml.
I'll give an example of how I'm handling this;

```
@"<input id='Checkbox1' type='checkbox'" + CheckBox1Label.Text + @" />";
```

So it's going to be a very large piece and if anyone has another suggestion it would be great. But for now, this will work.